# Memory leaks java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jmap

my java application, always needs more and more memory (starting at ~40mb, after 2 days about 140mb)

I used

```
./jmap -histo 17364 | head -10 
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:       1814362       68884536  [C
   2:       1813805       29020880  java.lang.String
   3:          1604        9989632  [B
   4:          1333         266184  [I
   5:          5769         250376  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   6:          2410         235720  java.lang.Class
   7:          2982         119280  java.util.HashMap
```

to get a feeling what is allocating this memory. Is there any way to detect in which actual java class is using these char-Arrays and strings?

Comment: You could try to use a profiler. Also change the GC settings mby its the cause of the memory increase, how do you run your app?

Comment: Try VisualVm. https://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: A start could be to look up places where `new String` or `new char[]` is used. Then check if references on them could be leaked. But a profiler - as kunpapa suggests - is your best chance.

Comment: can VisualVM read memory infos from remote devices? Because the application is running on an arm board with no gui. I tried jvisualvm, but that can only read memory infos from local VM

Comment: @kunpapa what do you mean with change GC settings?

Comment: Can you run it on your Development-Environment instead of the remote arm board? Which VM are you using? Oracle?

Comment: I'm not sure if the memory increase will be visible there, because the applications exchanges a lot of data with machines etc..It also may be a arm problem? yes i use Oracle

Comment: You can change some garbage collector options at the launch command. Check this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to do heap analysis , generate a heap dump using jmap 
   -dump:file=fileLocation PID , after that you can open the generated heap dump using Eclipse MAT .